# How to get a screenshot/preview of another website

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, backend, screen-scraping, headless-browser

**Is there a way in which you can get a screenshot of another websites pages?**

e.g: you introduce a url in an input, hit enter, and a script gives you a screenshot of the site you put in. I manage to do it with headless browsers, but I fear that could take too much resources and time, to launch. let's say phantomjs each time the input is used the headless browser would need to get the new data, I investigate HotJar, it does something similar to what I'm looking for, but it gives you a script that you must put into the page header, which is fine by me, afterwards, you get a preview, how does it work?, and how can one replicate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want a print screen of your page or someone else's?

### Own page

Use puppeteer or phantomJS with Beverly build of your site, this way you will only run it when it changes, and have a screenshot ready at any time.

### Foreign page

#### You have access to it (the owner runs your script)

Either try to get into his build pipeline, and use solution from above.

Or use this solution [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take in-browser screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-in-browser-screenshots/6678156#6678156).

#### You don't have any access

Use some long-running process that will give you screenshot when asked.

Imagine a server with one URL endpoint: `screenshot.example.com?facebook.com`.

The long-running server has a puppeteer/phantomJS instance ready to go when given URL, it will flood that page, get the screenshot and send it back. The browser will actually think of it as a slow ping image request.

Comment: Any idea of how an script like that would work?, (referring to your second suggestion), I only imagine sending the html and css to the server, but I'm not sure if there's a more efficient aproach

Comment: Be more precise, there is a solution for all 3 cases, which one is yours, what have you tried? Sending HTML + CSS to server is completely wrong, it won't do anything good there.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this with [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/)

install with: `npm i puppeteer`

save the following code to `example.js`

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

and run it with:
`node example.js`

Comment: OP said: `I fear that could take too much resources and time, to launch`. You don't address that in any way.